# C# WPF DataGrid column header style error Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, material-design-in-xaml, datagridcolumnheader

I'm using **C# WPF** .NET Core 6 also **Material Design Theme** nuget, I have problem with DataGrid's Column Header Style
I have Set a Style for Column Headers of my **DataGrid**

App.xaml :

```
 <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue.xaml" />
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue.xaml" />
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue.xaml" />
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UiDictionary/Greeny.xaml" />
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Greeny.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    x:Name="GreenyTheme">
 <Style x:Key="CenteryHeaderstyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="44"/>
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyWindow.xaml :

```
<DataGrid   x:Name="INVO_LST_sub"
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteryHeaderstyle}"     
    SelectedIndex="0"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Contained"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FACTOR22_INVO_DATA}"
    IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="INVO_LST_sub_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged"     
    Margin="3,241,6,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  SelectionUnit="FullRow"   BorderThickness="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NAME_CODE_COLUMN" Binding="{Binding NAME_CODE,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="NAME" Width="auto" MinWidth="50" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="VAHED_K_COLUMN"  
            Width="auto"   MinWidth="90" Header=" واحد کالا " Visibility="Visible" 
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding VAHED_K, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="NAMES" SelectedValuePath="VAHED">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I'm trying to enter some data into my DataGrid suddenly I get this error in my XAML (Binding failures) :

> HorizontalGridLinesBrush  DataGridColumnHeader.BorderBrush    Brush   Cannot
> find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1'.
>
> GridLinesVisibility   DataGridColumnHeader.BorderThickness    Thickness   Cannot
> find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1'.

[MyWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ8Wm.png)

After a lot of Debugging I found out if I remove this `BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}"` from My Style `<Style x:Key="CenteryHeaderstyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">`
***It would be fixed*** !

The point is I want to keep the default Style of Material Design for my DataGrid but change some things

How do I fix those errors ?